# Trouble understanding Longest Increasing Subsequence

Tags: math

I have been trying understand the concept of LIS and have found the following example on Wikipedia as a reference for my question.

```
In the first 16 terms of the binary:
0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15
a longest increasing subsequence is:
0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15.
```

My question really is, why those numbers. Wouldn't the LIS be all of the numbers sorted from lowest to highest, and the length of the LIS would be the same length as the original sequence assuming there are no duplicate integers? For example:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

Here we have a sequence of increasing numbers. Isn't that the longest increasing subsequence? What am I not understanding?

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 is not a valid sequence within 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15. The original order of the set matters. When finding a sequence, you cannot move backwards through the set and you cannot change the order of the original set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters in a sequence. By sorting it, you're changing it to a different sequence.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence):

> In mathematics, a subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some elements **without changing the order of the remaining elements.**

So, the goal in finding the longest increasing subsequence is to find the longest list of elements in the sequence that are in sorted order, but without changing the order of the original sequence.

Comment: The bold part really demystified my misunderstanding. Great answer overall.